# Why doesn't && in one if state work with this problem?

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements, operators

I first tried writing this code using one if-statement because I thought that it made sense since the index has to be even and the element has to be even and same with odd numbers and index, but it did not work. This code does not work:

```
1.    function isSpecialArray(arr) {
   //iterate through array
 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   if((i % 2 === 0 && arr[i] % 2 !== 0) && (i % 2 === 1 && arr[i] % 2 !== 1)){
     return false;
   }
  }
  return true;
   
}

console.log(isSpecialArray([2, 7, 4, 9, 6, 1, 6, 3]));
```

but, works with this code:

```
2.    

function isSpecialArray(arr) {
//iterate through array
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
 // console.log(arr[i] % 2 === 0 && i % 2 !== 0);
  if(i % 2 === 0 ){
    if(arr[i] % 2 !== 0){
      return false
    }
  }
  
  if(i % 2 == 1){
    if(arr[i] % 2 !== 1){
      return false;
     }
   }
    
   }
  
   return true;
   }
```

Comment: `i % 2 === 0`...lots of `&&`... `i % 2 === 1` - do you think these can be true at the same time?

Comment: Your code says "if the remainder of dividing `i` by 2 is zero ... and ... the remainder of dividing `i` by two is *not*  zero", both of those things cannot be true. Think about what the word "and" means.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code is carrying out a different sort of logic than your second. Spelling out your second:

```
function isSpecialArray(arr) {
    //iterate through array
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // first section
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 !== 0) {
                return false
            }
        }
        // second section
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 !== 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

On each iteration:

- In the first section, you check if the index and the element are even. If so, you return false. Otherwise, you check:
- In the second section, you check if the index and the element are odd. If so, you return false.

It's essentially OR logic there. So you should put `||` in your first code instead of `&&`:

```
if((i % 2 === 0 && arr[i] % 2 !== 0) && (i % 2 === 1 && arr[i] % 2 !== 1)){
```

should be

```
if((i % 2 === 0 && arr[i] % 2 !== 0) || (i % 2 === 1 && arr[i] % 2 !== 1)){
//                                   ^^
```

Your existing first code checks if the index is even *and* the value there is odd *and* that the index is odd *and* that the value there is even - which can never be true.

Answer (score -1):

```js
1.    function isSpecialArray(arr) {
   //iterate through array
 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
// the error was that you shouldve aded an OR between the two statements not an AND
   if((i % 2 === 0 && arr[i] % 2 !== 0) || (i % 2 === 1 && arr[i] % 2 !== 1)){
     return false;
   }
  }
  return true;
   
}

console.log(isSpecialArray([2, 7, 4, 9, 6, 1, 6, 3]));
```